# Ribbon changes are not published

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon

Recently I've faced this strange problem:

I changed a ribbon for Invoice entity on the development environment,  exported the solution as managed,  imported this solution to another environment,  published it and nothing happens.

I checked the `customization.xml` file and found all my changes there.

Next, I checked the `solution.xml` and found that `RibbonDiffXml` root component is included inside the solution.

But when I checked `Ribbon*` tables inside SQL database, I found that relevant commands and rules were not updated.

Does anyone can assist me in solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try This tool whcih is the best way to edit Ribbon.

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmmusings/archive/2012/09/12/crm-2011-ribbon-workbench-getting-guids-from-selected-records-in-the-grid.aspx#.UeZA-o3WWzQ

It is working with RU 12